# Prove that there is a 1-1 correspondence between the set of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z}$ and the set of the positive divisors of $N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Im interested in the above Proof, is because I have the intiuition that it is not true at all, because for example, all the primes have exactly 2 positive divisors 1 an themselves, How Can I prove or disprove this fact? Thank I need your help and I really want to figure this out please :).

**Well what I have attempted is to note that  $\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group then we know that evey subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic then but then I dont know how to justificate that $d$ has to be the generator and how to prove that there exits a bijection thank you :) I hope this help to have answers :)**

Comment: Well but $\mathbb Z/ p \mathbb Z$ where $p$ is prime also just has two subgroups: $\{\bar 0\}$ and $\mathbb Z/ p \mathbb Z$, so that's not valid argument.

Comment: Well that is the case, I think that the bijection should come in the number of positive divisors, but as you say that is wrong then which could be that invertible function ?

Comment: The proofs I know are pretty straightforward. Can you give some context as to what experience you already have so we can present the one that is closest to your level?

Comment: Yes, I am in an introductory course to modern Algebra :)

Comment: Do you have knowledge about cyclic groups and the Langrange theorem?

Comment: Is that a good context? or do you want somo other info.?

Comment: Yes, about the cyclic group, but not at all to the Lagrange theorem :), but I think we can use it :)

Comment: I am back in the dicussion :), what can you tell me about the problem ? :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

every (additive) subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ takes the form $k\mathbb{Z}$. suppose we have two such subgroups, $m\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\mathbb{Z}$. then the second is a subgroup of the first if and only if $m$ is a divisor $n$.

thus any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ which contains $N\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to a divisor of $N$, and this correspondence is $1-1$.

when you take the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z}$, the whole of $N\mathbb{Z}$ is reduced to the identity (you may think of this as an organized collapsing of most of the structure of $\mathbb{Z}$), and the subgroups of the quotient group are the images of precisely those subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ which contain $N\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thank you @DavidHolden and I have a question, Can I say it like that or it needs more formality ?, Thank you a lot :)

Comment: i think a little more formality would be good. i was just trying to convey an intuition of the principle. what is really involved here is a canonical isomorphism between the finite lattice of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $N\mathbb{Z}$ and the finite lattice of subgroups contained within $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$. this reverses the inclusion relationships, however.

Comment: Can you post that isomorphism please :)

Comment: Can you complete your answer with that and with the explicit 1-1 correspondence please :)

Comment: Is because of what I post of the proof-writting :) thanks